# Why use aload_0 in Jasmin HelloWorld?

Tags: java, jasmin

There is the start of official Jasmin HelloWorld example.

```
.class public NoJad.j
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
   aload_0

   invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
   return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   .limit stack 2
...
```

Why there is `aload_0` instruction? What does local var 0 consists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is calling a constructor of a base class (`Object` in this case):

```
this.super();
```

In non-static methods local variable under index `0` is always `this` reference so `aload_0` pushes `this` reference at the top of the reference stack. Then `invokenonvirtual` calls designated method (`Object/<init>()`) on an object at the top of the stack (`this`).